# cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, protractor

Hi i have written this code in login-page.js

[image]

i dont know why i am getting error 
Failed: Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined

I had called this page on login_spec.js

[image]

I am unable to continue this in protractor tests

Comment: Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this` instead of `login_page` to reference the current page object:

```
this.login = function (username, password) {
    this.userInput.sendKeys(username);
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do it like this:

```
//conf.js
module.exports = { 
config: {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['epLogin.spec.js'],
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome'
  }   
},  
params: {
login: {
  email: 'default',
  password: 'default'
    }   
  }
}
//pageObject
    this.login = function(email, password){
    this.email.clear();
    this.email.sendKeys(email);
    this.password.clear();
    this.password.sendKeys(password);
    this.loginButton.click();
//basic login example
}; 

 //spec.js
var loginpage = require ('/path'),
config = ('/conf.js'),
user;

beforeEach(function(){
var user = new loginpage();
});

describe('example', function(){
it('login', function(){
    user.get(); //per picture above
    user.login(config.params.login.email, config.params.login.password); 
    //assuming you've defined params & login function in ur PO
});
});
```